# Setting a background view animation for google card view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view, android-cardview

I'm writing an android app which uses romannurik`s Android-SwipeToDismiss.
I'm using google cardview for my view items.
Swiping the cards is enabled in the app using the above romannuriks library.

Now i'm facing difficulty in figuring out regarding how to make another view come in background while i'm swiping the card, just like the implementation in gmail.
When I swipe gmail card, I get background view containing archive and undo.

Any ideas regarding how to implement this would be really helpful.